# Installing List of font Pragmatically by vb.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, fonts

I have fonts folder contains  font with extension **"*.ttf"**, I need to install all the fonts in the user's computer to use my programs with these fonts.

Comment: Or use a [PrivateFontCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection), loading Fonts from both Files or Project Resources. Some examples using both methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57231407/7444103). If you really want to add the Fonts to the system Fonts collection, then probably this: [How to install a Windows Font](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14796255/7444103)

Comment: If you instead want to add your Fonts to the system Fonts only temporarily (while your Process is active), probably [AddFontMemResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontmemresourceex). If you want the Fonts to persist, you have to add an entry to the Registry. [AddFontResourceEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-addfontresourceexw) adds Fonts for the current User session that can be marked as `Private` instead.

Comment: Note that the code in *How to install a Windows Font* is a copy/paste of some other Web resource that is missing the broadcast of `WM_FONTCHANGE` (call `SendMessage` with `hWnd` set to `HWND_BROADCAST`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First You need Execute method to install font on Startup

```
  Public _pfc As PrivateFontCollection = Nothing

    Sub Installfont() 
        Try
            'INIT THE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc = New PrivateFontCollection
            'LOAD MEMORY POINTER FOR FONT RESOURCE
            Dim fontMemPointer As IntPtr =
            Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(My.Resources.MyFont.Length)
            'COPY THE DATA TO THE MEMORY LOCATION
            Marshal.Copy(My.Resources.MyFont, 0, fontMemPointer, My.Resources.MyFont.Length)
            'LOAD THE MEMORY FONT INTO THE PRIVATE FONT COLLECTION
            _pfc.AddMemoryFont(fontMemPointer, My.Resources.MyFont.Length)
            'FREE UNSAFE MEMORY
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(fontMemPointer)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
           MessageBox(ex.Message)

            Return False
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Second Method to Change Font in Form

```
 Sub Usefont(ByVal frm As Form)
            Dim toVisit As New List(Of Control) From {
                frm}
            toVisit.Add(frm)
            Do Until (toVisit.Count = 0)
                Dim cur As Control = toVisit(0)
                toVisit.RemoveAt(0)
                frm.Font = New Font(_pfc.Families(0), frm.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                For Each child As Control In cur.Controls
                    toVisit.Add(child)
                    child.Font = New Font(_pfc.Families(0), child.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold)
                Next
            Loop
        End If
    End Sub
```